# Call a function when user closes tab in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7, angular10

I would like to call a function when user closes the tab. I have used hostlistener to fire a event when user closes the tab and a popup appears with cancel and leave button. I need to call a function when user clicks the leave button. Below is the code I have written and I need to call myFunction() when user clicks on leave button.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
 beforeunloadHandler(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 return false;   
}

myFunction(){
 //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to the listener to the event of closing tab in your class, by calling your function with the key `this`.

```
 @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
   beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
   this.myFunction(event)
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;   
  }
  unloadHandler(event) {
    this.myFunction(event)
    // ...
  }

 
  

myFunction(event){
 console.log("this event come form: ", event)
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is the function will get called on click of the x icon in the tab. Right now i get a popup with a message 'Are u sure u want to leave?' and two buttons 'cancel' and 'leave' . I want the function to be called only when i click the leave button. With the solution u gave the function will get fired even before the popup appears.

Comment: Ok, so please add rest of code. The solution will be a observable or subscription, when in your method build in the pop up component emmit the ‘leave’ it will call myFunction()

Answer (score 0):

You can try ngOnDestroy if you are changing tab then this method will invoke and you can call your function!!

ngOnDestroy(): void {
`enter code here`
}